# How to center multiple SVG's to the same point?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, center

This is the look I am trying to achieve in my side navigation: 
[image]

This is my HTML:

```css
/* SIDE NAVIGATION */
    .side-navigation {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     background-color: #4D4A75;
    }
    #_x31_0_20_ .st0,
    #_x37__17_ .st0,
    #_x35__10_ .st0,
    #_x32__16_ .st0 {
     fill: #9A99B9;
    }
    .side-navigation >* {
     width: 56px;
     height: 56px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="side-navigation">
    
        <div class="dashboard">
         <svg class="dashboard-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
         <style type="text/css">
          .st0{fill:black;}
         </style>
         <g id="_x31_0_20_">
          <g>
           <path class="st0" d="M25,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,16.7,23.3,18,25,18z M24,14h2v2h-2V14z M25,26
           c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,24.7,23.3,26,25,26z M24,22h2v2h-2V22z M17,26c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3
           c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,24.7,15.3,26,17,26z M16,22h2v2h-2V22z M28,0H6C3.8,0,2,1.8,2,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h22
           c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H6c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V8h26V28z M30,6H4V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h22
           c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V6z M17,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,16.7,15.3,18,17,18z M16,14h2v2h-2V14z M9,26
           c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,24.7,7.3,26,9,26z M8,22h2v2H8V22z M9,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3
           c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,16.7,7.3,18,9,18z M8,14h2v2H8V14z"/>
          </g>
         </g>
         </svg>
        </div>
    
        <div class="members">
         <svg class="members-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <style type="text/css">
          .st0{fill:black;}
          </style>
          <g id="_x37__17_">
           <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M18,16.4c1.3-1.7,2-3.9,2-6.4c0-5.5-4-10-9-10C6,0,2,4.5,2,10c0,2.4,0.8,4.6,2,6.4c-2.3,0.8-4,3-4,5.6v4
           c0,3.3,2.7,6,6,6h10c3.3,0,6-2.7,6-6v-4C22,19.4,20.3,17.2,18,16.4z M4,10c0-4.4,3.1-8,7-8c3.9,0,7,3.6,7,8s-3.1,8-7,8
           C7.1,18,4,14.4,4,10z M20,25.5c0,2.5-2.2,4.5-4.9,4.5H6.9C4.2,30,2,28,2,25.5v-3c0-2.1,1.6-3.9,3.8-4.4C7.2,19.3,9,20,11,20
           c2,0,3.8-0.7,5.2-1.9c2.2,0.5,3.8,2.2,3.8,4.4V25.5z M23,8h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1
           C22,7.6,22.4,8,23,8z M31,24h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,24.4,31.6,24,31,24z M31,12h-8
           c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,12.4,31.6,12,31,12z M31,18h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6
           c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,18.4,31.6,18,31,18z"/>
           </g>
          </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
    
        <div class="social-visits">
         <svg class="social-visits-svg"version="1.1" id="Line_12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <style type="text/css">
          .st0{fill:black;}
          </style>
          <g id="_x35__10_">
           <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M14,0h-2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v28c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C16,0.9,15.1,0,14,0z M14,29
           c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V3c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M4,9H2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2
           c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V11C6,9.9,5.1,9,4,9z M4,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V12c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M24,16h-2
           c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v12c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V18C26,16.9,25.1,16,24,16z M24,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V19
           c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z"/>
           </g>
          </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
    
        <div class="settings-side">
         <svg class="settings-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
         <style type="text/css">
          .st0{fill:black;}
         </style>
         <g id="_x32__16_">
          <g>
           <path class="st0" d="M26,24H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1
           c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,24.4,26.6,24,26,24z M11,27.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4
           c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,26.3,12.3,27.4,11,27.4z M26,8H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3C9.1,5,7.6,6.3,7.1,8H6
           C5.4,8,5,8.4,5,9c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,8.4,26.6,8,26,8z M11,11.4
           c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,10.3,12.3,11.4,11,11.4z M26,16h-2.1
           c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h10.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26
           c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,16.4,26.6,16,26,16z M20,19.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4
           C22.4,18.3,21.3,19.4,20,19.4z M28,0H4C1.8,0,0,1.8,0,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h24c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28
           c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H4c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h24c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V28z"/>
          </g>
         </g>
         </svg>
        </div>
    
       </div>
```

As you can see, its not the SVG that needs centering, its the path within them. Would I only be able to achieve the desired look by adding a transform property to the g elements? How many possible solutions are there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using `flex-flow: column;`.

```css
/* SIDE NAVIGATION */

.side-navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #4D4A75;
  width: 100px;
}

.side-navigation div {
  padding: 1em;
}

#_x31_0_20_ .st0,
#_x37__17_ .st0,
#_x35__10_ .st0,
#_x32__16_ .st0 {
  fill: #9A99B9;
}

.side-navigation>* {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-navigation">

  <div class="dashboard">
    <svg class="dashboard-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .st0{fill:black;}
                    </style>
                    <g id="_x31_0_20_">
                        <g>
                            <path class="st0" d="M25,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,16.7,23.3,18,25,18z M24,14h2v2h-2V14z M25,26
                            c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,24.7,23.3,26,25,26z M24,22h2v2h-2V22z M17,26c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3
                            c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,24.7,15.3,26,17,26z M16,22h2v2h-2V22z M28,0H6C3.8,0,2,1.8,2,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h22
                            c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H6c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V8h26V28z M30,6H4V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h22
                            c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V6z M17,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,16.7,15.3,18,17,18z M16,14h2v2h-2V14z M9,26
                            c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,24.7,7.3,26,9,26z M8,22h2v2H8V22z M9,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3
                            c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,16.7,7.3,18,9,18z M8,14h2v2H8V14z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="members">
    <svg class="members-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <style type="text/css">
                     .st0{fill:black;}
                    </style>
                    <g id="_x37__17_">
                        <g>
                            <path class="st0" d="M18,16.4c1.3-1.7,2-3.9,2-6.4c0-5.5-4-10-9-10C6,0,2,4.5,2,10c0,2.4,0.8,4.6,2,6.4c-2.3,0.8-4,3-4,5.6v4
                            c0,3.3,2.7,6,6,6h10c3.3,0,6-2.7,6-6v-4C22,19.4,20.3,17.2,18,16.4z M4,10c0-4.4,3.1-8,7-8c3.9,0,7,3.6,7,8s-3.1,8-7,8
                            C7.1,18,4,14.4,4,10z M20,25.5c0,2.5-2.2,4.5-4.9,4.5H6.9C4.2,30,2,28,2,25.5v-3c0-2.1,1.6-3.9,3.8-4.4C7.2,19.3,9,20,11,20
                            c2,0,3.8-0.7,5.2-1.9c2.2,0.5,3.8,2.2,3.8,4.4V25.5z M23,8h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1
                            C22,7.6,22.4,8,23,8z M31,24h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,24.4,31.6,24,31,24z M31,12h-8
                            c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,12.4,31.6,12,31,12z M31,18h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6
                            c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,18.4,31.6,18,31,18z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="social-visits">
    <svg class="social-visits-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <style type="text/css">
                     .st0{fill:black;}
                    </style>
                    <g id="_x35__10_">
                        <g>
                            <path class="st0" d="M14,0h-2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v28c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C16,0.9,15.1,0,14,0z M14,29
                            c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V3c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M4,9H2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2
                            c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V11C6,9.9,5.1,9,4,9z M4,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V12c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M24,16h-2
                            c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v12c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V18C26,16.9,25.1,16,24,16z M24,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V19
                            c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                     </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="settings-side">
    <svg class="settings-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .st0{fill:black;}
                    </style>
                    <g id="_x32__16_">
                        <g>
                            <path class="st0" d="M26,24H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1
                            c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,24.4,26.6,24,26,24z M11,27.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4
                            c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,26.3,12.3,27.4,11,27.4z M26,8H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3C9.1,5,7.6,6.3,7.1,8H6
                            C5.4,8,5,8.4,5,9c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,8.4,26.6,8,26,8z M11,11.4
                            c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,10.3,12.3,11.4,11,11.4z M26,16h-2.1
                            c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h10.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26
                            c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,16.4,26.6,16,26,16z M20,19.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4
                            C22.4,18.3,21.3,19.4,20,19.4z M28,0H4C1.8,0,0,1.8,0,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h24c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28
                            c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H4c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h24c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V28z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```